# Convert a list of strings to a List of objects

Tags: c#, list

In MVC, I have been given POST data which comes from a form that has rows of input cells, which eventually comes in as a NameValueCollection of the form elements and their submitted values that looks like this (excerpt):

```
[47]: "[DocStatus][1][Status]"
[48]: "[DocStatus][1][Notes]"
[49]: "[DocStatus][2][Status]"
[50]: "[DocStatus][2][Notes]"
[51]: "[DocStatus][3][Status]"
[52]: "[DocStatus][3][Notes]"
```

I'm trying to convert these entries into their representing object (i.e. a List of `DocStatus` items with properties of `Status` and `Notes`).

I have thought of iterating and decoding the collection by key and filling out a list that way, but I thought that someone might have a better solution.

Yes, I know that the MVC normally does this automatically if you put it in the function call correctly, but this is not a by-the-books function, and I must start with this NameValueCollection object.

Comment: So you can't use model binding? If not, then simply split the string and manually parse each element. Model binding is the ideal approach and the one I listed is almost at the top of the list of non-ideal solutions.

Comment: I agree I'm not in an ideal solution at all. :(  Fun fact: The data that goes into the page came from a model, but the way it's being given back in the POST means it's mixed up with a bunch of other stuff on the page.  I was going to try multiple-submit so I could model bind, but that failed epically.